# React Strict mode causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js and have the following hook;

```
export function useStopwatch(defaultValue = 0) {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(defaultValue)
  const {set: startInterval, clear: stopInterval} = useInterval()
  var offset = 0;
  function delta() {
    let now = Date.now()
    let delta =  now - offset;
    offset = now
    return delta
  }
  function update() {
    setTimer(prev => prev+delta())
  }
  function start() {
      offset = Date.now();
      startInterval(update, 1)
  }
  function reset() {
    stopInterval()
    setTimer(0)
  }
  return { time: Round(timer/1000, 2), start, stop: stopInterval, reset }
}

export function useInterval() {
  const [reference, setReference] = useState<number | undefined>()

  function set(callback: () => void, delay: number) {
    if (!reference) {
      setReference(window.setInterval(callback, delay))
    }
  }

  function clear() {
    if (reference) {
      clearInterval(reference)
      setReference(undefined)
    }
  }

  return { set, clear }
}
```

This code works as expected in the browser (strict mode off) when I display `time` (`time` acts as a stopwatch) from `useStopwatch()`, when I turn strict mode on from the config. the hook seems to take a while to update its state, meaning that the stopwatch will pause for a second or two before adding a few milliseconds to the stopwatch.

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
  }
```

From what I can tell strict mode only effects development and it puts in place various checks to help you write cleaner/safer code. However with strict mode enabled the `timer` seems to update much slower. I have found that `setTimer` does trigger appropriately but the state isn't set as frequently.

Why is this?

I have checked the console and there are no warnings/errors.

Comment: As of react 18, with the `useEffect` double rendering changes this has me wondering if there is a problem with my code that strict mode highlights and isn't telling me, or if there is a problem with strict mode